# What's the purpose of the Duration property in the TSkAnimatedPaintBox component?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, skia, skia4delphi

What's the real role for the `Duration` property in the `TSkAnimatedPaintBox` component in the Skia Library for Delphi? Setting it to 100000 or 1000 does nothing different. I don't see any changes.

What is the `Duration` property used for or how does it work?

I am using Embarcadero Delphi 12 IDE, FireMonkey (FMX) Framework, Delphi Programming Language.

Comment: Which type of animation are you using? It is possible that `Duration` affects only types of animation that don't already contain information about animation duration in themselves.